# do the 17 inch rims will fit BMW e83 from the other BMW models?

Tags: bmw, wheels

Looking to buy a used wheel (tire + rim) for the spare for my BMW e83, but can't find my model in the list. Is there any difference lets say for F30 (320i, i328i) and x3 wheels? Aside from visual difference of corse.

To be short, the question is can I put the wheel from 320i (17inch) to my x3 (17 inch also)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find wheels the same size, offset, pcd and centre bore as your car.

Looking online, it looks like your car has a PCD of 5x120, centre bore of 72.6 and size & offset of either 8Jx17 ET46 or 7Jx17 ET39

It appears that E30s have the same PCD and centre bore, but different offsets - they would probably physically fit the car, but would stick out more or less than your other wheels, which would be bad for handling.

Comment: Thank you for the terms. With your post I have found a link
http://www.wheelfitment.eu/car/BMW/X3%20E83%20(2004%20-%202010).html

Comment: if its possible, just add this link to your answer. Thats the perfect website to figure out the wheels!